# NoClassDefFoundError while using Asynchronous http request

Tags: eclipse, asynchronous, jboss, jms, message-driven-bean

I've got an strange problem when trying to combine an JMS with MDB queue. The thing is that I want to send an JMS to the queue, and when receiving the message, make 2 asynchronous http get to a server.

I've managed to set up the queue and send/receive messages. Also, I can make a single http or synchronous, but when I try to do an asynchronous http get, I get the NoClassDefFoundError. I've been using the Apache example class 
hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore-nio/examples/org/apache/http/examples/nio/NHttpClient.java

And it works fine when using as a java aplication, but I get NoClassDefFOundError when trying to call from the MDB.

I'm using JBoss 6 and Eclipse

13:55:54,073 ERROR [STDERR] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/nio/NHttpClientEventHandler

13:55:54,073 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.mdb.QueueListenerMDB.onMessage(QueueListenerMDB.java:59)

13:55:54,074 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

13:55:54,074 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

13:55:54,074 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

13:55:54,074 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

13:55:54,075 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeTarget(MethodInvocation.java:122)

13:55:54,075 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:111)

13:55:54,075 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.container.ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.invokeNext(ContainerMethodInvocationWrapper.java:72)

13:55:54,076 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.invoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:76)

13:55:54,076 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InterceptorSequencer.aroundInvoke(InterceptorSequencer.java:62)

13:55:54,077 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

13:55:54,077 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)

13:55:54,077 ERROR [STDERR]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)

13:55:54,077 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)

13:55:54,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.PerJoinpointAdvice.invoke(PerJoinpointAdvice.java:174)

13:55:54,078 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,079 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.fillMethod(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:74)

13:55:54,079 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1427582905.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_fillMethod_1427582905.java)

13:55:54,080 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,080 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor.setup(InvocationContextInterceptor.java:90)

13:55:54,080 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.advice.org.jboss.ejb3.interceptors.aop.InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1427582905.invoke(InvocationContextInterceptor_z_setup_1427582905.java)

13:55:54,080 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,081 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.async.impl.interceptor.AsynchronousServerInterceptor.invoke(AsynchronousServerInterceptor.java:110)

13:55:54,081 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,081 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.connectionmanager.CachedConnectionInterceptor.invoke(CachedConnectionInterceptor.java:62)

13:55:54,081 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,082 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.entity.TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.invoke(TransactionScopedEntityManagerInterceptor.java:56)

13:55:54,082 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,082 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.AllowedOperationsInterceptor.invoke(AllowedOperationsInterceptor.java:47)

13:55:54,082 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,083 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)

13:55:54,083 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,084 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessInstanceInterceptor.invoke(StatelessInstanceInterceptor.java:68)

13:55:54,085 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,085 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.InvocationContextAdapter.proceed(InvocationContextAdapter.java:70)

13:55:54,085 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:223)

13:55:54,085 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:353)

13:55:54,086 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.impl.CMTTxInterceptor.invoke(CMTTxInterceptor.java:209)

13:55:54,086 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx2.aop.CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.invoke(CMTTxInterceptorWrapper.java:52)

13:55:54,086 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,086 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.tx.NullInterceptor.invoke(NullInterceptor.java:42)

13:55:54,087 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,087 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.security.Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.invoke(Ejb3AuthenticationInterceptorv2.java:79)

13:55:54,089 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,089 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.invoke(BlockContainerShutdownInterceptor.java:67)

13:55:54,089 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,090 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.core.context.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:47)

13:55:54,090 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,090 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aspects.currentinvocation.CurrentInvocationInterceptor.invoke(CurrentInvocationInterceptor.java:67)

13:55:54,091 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,091 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.interceptor.EJB3TCCLInterceptor.invoke(EJB3TCCLInterceptor.java:86)

13:55:54,091 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.aop.joinpoint.MethodInvocation.invokeNext(MethodInvocation.java:102)

13:55:54,092 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.MessagingContainer.localInvoke(MessagingContainer.java:306)

13:55:54,092 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.delivery(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:299)

13:55:54,092 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ejb3.mdb.inflow.MessageInflowLocalProxy.invoke(MessageInflowLocalProxy.java:152)

13:55:54,093 ERROR [STDERR]     at $Proxy130.onMessage(Unknown Source)

13:55:54,093 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.ra.inflow.HornetQMessageHandler.onMessage(HornetQMessageHandler.java:256)

13:55:54,094 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:822)

13:55:54,094 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$100(ClientConsumerImpl.java:46)

13:55:54,095 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:940)

13:55:54,095 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.hornetq.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$1.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:100)

13:55:54,095 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)

13:55:54,096 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)

13:55:54,098 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

13:55:54,098 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.nio.NHttpClientEventHandler from BaseClassLoader@72d47b5a{vfs:///C:/Users/Guillermo/Documents/Workspace%20Eclipse/.metadata/.plugins/org.jboss.ide.eclipse.as.core/JBoss_6.0_Runtime_Server1379590260770/deploy/FirstMDBProyect.jar}

13:55:54,099 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.classloader.spi.base.BaseClassLoader.loadClass(BaseClassLoader.java:480)

13:55:54,099 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)

13:55:54,099 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 64 more

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Please have a look at http://wso2.com/mailarchive/dev/2013-March/016528.html which looks like a similar issue (and not related to JMS/MDB but to the versions of Commons Httpclient jars).

Comment: Thanks, but I've already seen that page, and unfortunately wont resolve my issue

Comment: It was worth a try :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how to: I had to edit the server libs to include the missing files